# Does Selenium Support Drag / ClickAndHold on Headless Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, headless

I tried to use click and hold method inside a headless Chrome, but it's not working.

The algorithm works using a normal Chrome though.

Comment: Is running the same code in normal Chrome working ok?

Comment: Can we see your code ? It should work fine

Comment: Yes it supoort drag and drop , but it is very fast as compared to normal browser , give some explicit wait there.